# Jquery function with changeable value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm kinda new to Jquery/AJAX and I want to create a function out of this:

```
$("#inputpass").css({
"border-radius": "5px",
"font-weight":   "bolder",
"border":        "1px solid red"
});
```

The only problem is, that I don't know how to change #inputpass, I would like it to be that I can call the function: changeColor('#inputusername'); and that the CSS would go with inputusername.

I can make the function, but not with a changeable value. Thank you very much for helping! English isn't BTW my mother tongue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is trivial:

```
function changeColor(elem) {
    $(elem).css({
        "border-radius": "5px",
        "font-weight":   "bolder",
        "border":        "1px solid red"
    });
}

// now, for example:
changeColor('#inputusername');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TexasBrawler/e26o5e41/)

Comment: Thank you very much! I wasn't expecting an answer that fast :-) As soon as I can accept your answer, I will :)

Comment: Yes I will, after 10 minutes your answer will be accepted